# Removing only numbers at beginning of sentences in string - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

I need to remove numbers from within a string, but only if those numbers are at the beginning of a sentence. I don't want to remove numbers within sentences. For instance:

1There were 101 dalmatians in the room. 2 They had 2 parents.
[new line]3 The parents were named Pongo and Perdita.

In the above text, I want to remove the numbers at the beginning of each sentence, whether there is a space after the number or not, including if the number is the first character on a new line. So, the text in the string needs to become:

There were 101 dalmatians in the room. They had 2 parents.
[new line]The parents were named Pongo and Perdita.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enumerate the sentences, use regular expression to trim leading numbers, and build final string.

E.g.

```swift
let string = """
    1There were 101 dalmatians in the room. 2 They had 2 parents.
    3 The parents were named Pongo and Perdita.
    """

var result: String = ""
string.enumerateSubstrings(in: string.startIndex..., options: .bySentences) { substring, _, _, _ in
    guard
        let trimmed = substring?.replacingOccurrences(of: #"^\d+\s*"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression)
    else { return }
    result.append(trimmed)
}
print(result)
```

> There were 101 dalmatians in the room. They had 2 parents. 
> The parents were named Pongo and Perdita.

There are lots of permutations on the regex pattern. E.g. if you used `#"^\d+\.?\)?\s*"#`, it would also handle cases like “1. This is a test!” or “1) This is a test.” It just depends upon what variations you want to handle. But if you're just looking for digits only, with or without spaces, then `#"^\d+\s*"#` should be fine.

Comment: Why are you using guard on your substring? AFAIK it can only be nil when using `substringNotRequired` option **The enumerated substring. If substringNotRequired is included in opts, this parameter is nil for every execution of the closure.** Can it fail if we don't include substringNotRequired in options?

Comment: I generally safely unwrap optionals, rather than assuming that there can’t be some weird edge case that I might not have anticipated. So, the `guard` might not be needed, but seems prudent, nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm very new to this, so it will take me some time to understand properly what is happening, but there's lots to go on. I didn't know about Regex, for instance. Your answer did exactly what I asked for. Sadly I missed a combination that needs to be accounted for - numbers with characters on either side, for instance ".4T". Hopefully I can figure out Regex to solve this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a not so fancy solution using a basic for loop to go through each character of the string and a boolean to keep track if we are or aren't checking for a digit at the start of the sentence.

```
var checkForDigit = true // State of loop
var digitFound = false // Need this to ignore space after digit 
var output = ""
for character in text {
    if character.isPunctuation {
        output.append(character)
        checkForDigit = true
        continue
    }

    if checkForDigit {
        if !character.isNumber {
            if digitFound && character.isWhitespace {
                continue
            }
            output.append(character)
            if !character.isWhitespace {
                checkForDigit = false
            }
        } else {
            digitFound = true
        }
        continue
    }
    digitFound = false
    output.append(character)
}
```

I have only tested it on the example in the question so it might need some tweaking

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed you were able to do it like this! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun. You can enumerate the sentences, get all sentence ranges and replace the ranges of the original string. To remove the numbers from the beginning of each sentence you can use collection method drop(while:) and drop all non letters characters  from your substrings (sentences):

```
extension Bool {
    var negated: Bool { !self }
}

var string = """
1There were 101 dalmatians in the room. 2 They had 2 parents.
3 The parents were named Pongo and Perdita.
"""
var ranges: [Range<String.Index>] = []

string.enumerateSubstrings(in: string.startIndex..., options: .bySentences) { _, range, _, _ in
    ranges.append(range)
}

for range in ranges.reversed() {
    string.replaceSubrange(range, with: string[range].drop(while: \.isLetter.negated))
}

string  // "There were 101 dalmatians in the room. They had 2 parents.\nThe parents were named Pongo and Perdita."
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I've said above, I'm new to this, so there's plenty for me to learn from what you've suggested. Thank you!